# How can I set a max. ExpirationDate TimeSpan on a azure Media Service Locator?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I mistakenly set the wrong time for several Locator Url's that are connected to uploaded videos.  I am now trying to correct by setting the locator to a MaxValue to ensure that it does not go away, as several others have already.  I tried to do the following, context.Locators.Create(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, outputAsset, AccessPermissions.Read, TimeSpan.MaxValue), and this only resulted in  "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime".  What is the Maximum timespan I can possibly set if I really do not want the locators to expire?

Comment: We usually use an expiration time span of 200 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set as 100 years as the expiryOn time, it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

100 years seem to be sufficient

```
TimeSpan.FromDays(36500)
```